# Django wont load static .css files error: 404 1689

Tags: css, django, static

Django was able to load a static .png file but not the static .css file, why?

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

css file

```
h1{
  color: red;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Django Guitar Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mysyle.css" %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <<h1>Hi, this is text</h1>
    <img src="{% static "images/a_picture.png" %}" alt="Uh oh, didn't show">
  </body>
</html>
```

file path

first_app/static/css/mystyle.css

first_app/static/css/images/a_picture.png

Comment: There is one "<" extra before h1 tag

Comment: {% static "css/mysyle.css" %} change to {% static "css/mystyle.css" %}

Comment: Spelling mistake in filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Spelling mistake

Change

```
{% static "css/mysyle.css" %}
```

to

```
{% static "css/mystyle.css" %}
```

Comment: I commented this. You too late :)

Comment: yeah that was the problem, not sure how I didn't see that--thnx

Answer (score 0):

in my case changed the structure to this:
├───myapp
│    ├───migrations
│    ├───templates
├───static
│    └───css
|         └───style.css
└───myproject
├───templates
└───registration

and worked.